# How do I edit project components in TRAC

Tags: trac

When creating New Ticket in the TRAC it shows a selectbox for component in the Ticket Properties. I only have two dummy options: component1 and component2.

How do I edit this list? How do I add more components to the project?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is via the [WebAdmin plugin](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/WebAdmin). You can easily edit your components, ticket types, severtities, etc from there.

As Oliver Giesen informs us in his comment: With trac 0.11 and higher, the WebAdmin plugin is already part of the standard install.

Comment: you might want to mention that WebAdmin is already bundled with trac 0.11.x - no need to install anything extra there

Answer (score 8):

```
trac-admin component list
    -- Show available components
trac-admin component add  
    -- Add a new component
trac-admin component rename  
    -- Rename a component
trac-admin component remove 
    -- Remove/uninstall component
trac-admin component chown  
    -- Change component ownership
```